# separate Error: load csv to hive

Tags: csv, tabs, hive

I am Cherry!

```
 add jar /home/hadoop/csv-serde.jar;
create database IF NOT EXISTS test;
use test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.neighbors(
    objID bigint ,
    NeighborObjID bigint ,
    distance float ,
    type smallint ,
    neighborType smallint ,
    mode tinyint ,
    neighborMode tinyint) row format serde  'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' with serdeproperties (
   "separatorChar" = "\t")stored as TextFile;
```

I cerate a table with 7 attributes. I load it to HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/hive/csv/Neighbors.csv /usr/hadoop/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs
```

I load it to neighbors.

```
 use test;
    add jar /home/hadoop/csv-serde.jar;
    LOAD DATA  INPATH '/usr/hadoop/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/Neighbors.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE neighbors;
```

There should be 7 arrributes.

```
select * from neighbors;
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064469  0.11240466522238592           6      3      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064470  0.21434291786709292           6      3      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064471  0.23417060042663973           6      6      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507934  1.2029018814611406E-3         6      6      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507935  0.11229523899396199           6      3      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507936  0.21438380604022358           6      3      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237666338097660047  1.7811731642581635E-3         6      6      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1237645876861272110  1237666338097660048  0.11403807309757029           6      3      2    2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
select objID from neighbors;
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064468  1.0369065814116625E-3         6      6      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064469  0.11240466522238592           6      3      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064470  0.21434291786709292           6      3      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237663542075064471  0.23417060042663973           6      6      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507934  1.2029018814611406E-3         6      6      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507935  0.11229523899396199           6      3      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237666299449507936  0.21438380604022358           6      3      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237666338097660047  1.7811731642581635E-3         6      6      2    2
1237645876861272110  1237666338097660048  0.11403807309757029           6      3      2    2
```

There is one attribute with all values and the others are all NULL.
Here is Neighbors.csv.[Neighbors.csv](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sjxA8PJ) The csv file is very big(100GB) and seven attributes are all in one column. I take 92KB a example.

1237645876861272071  1237645876861272078  0.32965707824169882           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144454  0.26459062942243383           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144458  0.39759983562125262           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144467  0.42354716397014541           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144474  0.34070753757945649           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296374  0.18245847995970663           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296375  5.4353586098331253E-3         3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296380  0.38719702159199682           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296384  0.33965518492584618           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296393  0.43922183220216948           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296395  0.49000926139721906           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296409  0.44651142644641773           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296411  0.39216278873263422           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296417  0.31949073955943957           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843296422  0.33711157914306916           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843361812  0.26280159296107986           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843361858  0.37196149776646037           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649909843361862  0.49007799303090271           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237650009161334811  0.18281445894897566           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237650009161334813  7.8938692921539429E-3         3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237650009161334885  0.43000492776202714           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237653011352453152  0.18222425001383408           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237653011352453154  0.28619458530146008           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237653011352453159  3.3057687354212687E-3         3      3      2    2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your data "TAB" separated? As I am seeing you are using `CSVFile`. If your data is `","` then you should use `separatorChar" = ",")` as data separator. If data is `"\t"` separated then there is no need of your UDF. We can recommend if could share your sample data?

Comment: Thanks. Neighbors.csv. http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sjxA8PJ

Comment: One quick and funny solution I can find at the moment. Replace  white-space with `","` using `sed` command before loading into `HDFS`.Then load new file into hdfs. Create a simple `external table` by specifying `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`. It should work.

Comment: Command to modify your file should be like this `sed -e 's/\s/,/g' Neighbors.csv > Neighbors.csv`.You can get `sed` command from here. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/replace-all-white-spaces-with-commas-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using modifying the file before loading into HDFS:

**Original Input:**

```
1237645876861272071  1237645876861272078  0.32965707824169882           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144454  0.26459062942243383           3      3      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144458  0.39759983562125262           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144467  0.42354716397014541           3      6      2    2
1237645876861272071  1237649806768144474  0.34070753757945649           3      6      2    2
```

Applied `sed` command to replace white-space with `","`

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' Neighbors.csv > Neighbors.csv
sed -e 's/,$//' Neighbors.csv > Neighbors.csv
```

The command will replace white-space with comma

**Modified Input:**

```
1237645876861272071,1237645876861272078,0.32965707824169882,3,3,2,2
1237645876861272071,1237649806768144454,0.26459062942243383,3,3,2,2
1237645876861272071,1237649806768144458,0.39759983562125262,3,6,2,2
1237645876861272071,1237649806768144467,0.42354716397014541,3,6,2,2
```

Loaded the file into HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -put Neighbors.csv /user/root/test/hive/
```

**Create table statement:**

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_Neighbors(
    objID string,
    NeighborObjID string ,
    distance string,
    type smallint ,
    neighborType smallint ,
    mode tinyint ,
    neighborMode tinyint) 
    row format delimited fields terminated by ','
    stored as textfile
    LOCATION '/user/root/test/hive/';
```